# MacBook Pro Broken Screen

Tags: macbook-pro

I have MacBook Pro with broken screen it works fine if set external display to mirror. Since I can’t force the MacBook in clampshell mode.

Any way to force MacBook to clampshell mode when the screen / cable is broken. Ideally I want to use multiple monitors (using MacBook as desktop).

Comment: Is the top case/display that physically damaged to the point that it cannot be closed?

Comment: I am able to close it, but macbook never goes into clampshell mode

Comment: i think some kind of sensor is broken, if there is any way to trigger clampshell from software that's what I was hoping

Comment: I believe with a strong magnet or something theres a way to do that, but im not sure how

Comment: A very hacky workaround might be to just place a small magnet on the correct spot on your MacBook (depending on model, this is usually on the left side of the device, somewhere in the area of the speaker or headphone jack). That is also what triggers your MacBook know it's shut. Perhaps add your MacBook model to your description so we can give you more detailed advice.

Comment: You could also disconnect the video cable inside the MacBook, that way it would essentially behave like a Mac Mini but I can't confirm this works with every model either.

Comment: Macbook Pro 16 Intel